# If href contains X, change href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a problem, that seemed trival at the beggining. There are several objects with class 'special' and for each of them there is a need to modify a href accordingly to the parameter. 
For example, if an url contains '#1' then it should be changed to '#HERE'.
See example here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/01geytk3/)

```
<a class="o-btn special" href="https://www.example.com/site#1">open</a><br>
<a class="o-btn special" href="https://www.example.com/site#2">open</a><br>
<a class="o-btn special" href="https://www.example.com/site#3">open</a><br>
<a class="o-btn special" href="https://www.example.com/site#4">open</a><br>
<a class="o-btn special" href="https://www.example.com/site#12">open</a><br>
```

```js
if ( $(".special").attr("href").indexOf('#1')>-1 )
                $(function(){$(".special").attr("href","https://www.example.com/site#HERE?".concat(URI(window.location.href).query()))}
else if ( $(".special").attr("href").indexOf('#2')>-1 )
                $(function(){$(".special").attr("href","https://www.example.com/site#2?".concat(URI(window.location.href).query()))}
else if ( $(".special").attr("href").indexOf('#3')>-1 )
                $(function(){$(".special").attr("href","https://www.example.com/site#3?".concat(URI(window.location.href).query()))}
else if ( $(".special").attr("href").indexOf('#4')>-1 )
                $(function(){$(".special").attr("href","https://www.example.com/site#4?".concat(URI(window.location.href).query()))}
else if ( $(".special").attr("href").indexOf('#5')>-1 )
                $(function(){$(".special").attr("href","https://www.example.com/site#5?".concat(URI(window.location.href).query()))}
else if ( $(".special").attr("href").indexOf('#6')>-1 )
                $(function(){$(".special").attr("href","https://www.example.com/site#6?".concat(URI(window.location.href).query()))}
else $(function()
                $(function(){$(".special").attr("href","https://www.example.com/site?".concat(URI(window.location.href).query()))})
```

The ifs seem to be working correctly, but I do not know why the part:

```
$(function(){ 
     $(".special").attr("href", "https://www.example.com/site#3?".concat(URI(window.location.href).query()))
}
```

is not.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, he's not using `.` for concatenation.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan he's using `.` for string function

Comment: And your fiddle is badly broken.

Comment: why are you using `$(function(){}` inside every block? can't you wrap all the ifs inside only one?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly goes wrong when you run your code?

Comment: @zahirdhada you're right. I'm going blind.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, happens to the best of us :-)

Comment: are you sure your javascript is correct? '.special' returns multiple elements but you seem to want to update just one at a time

Comment: @steo I need to change '.special' with href that contains specific value. There are multiple '.special' so I need ifs to assign different values to different links with the same class.

Comment: @EmreTürkiş my javascript for sure is not correct ;)  You are right -  '.special' element returns multiple values and for every different value I need to change href in a specific way. Not all links at the same time.

Comment: The main problem is that in first link 'site#1' is not changed to 'site#HERE'.

Comment: i would loop them with $( ".special" ).each() and then use your ifs to check the href and assing value;

Comment: Thank you all for interest, I will use skobaljic's solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can organize your script better way:

```js
$.fn.extend({
 fixLink: function () {
  return this.each(function (i) {
   var thisLink = $(this);
   var thisHref = thisLink.attr("href");
   var splited = thisHref.split('#');
   if (splited.length > 1) {
    var hash = splited.pop();
    switch( hash ) {
     case '1':
      thisHref = thisHref.replace('#1', '#HERE');
      break;
     case '12':
      thisHref = thisHref.replace('#12', '#SOMEWHERE');
      break;
     default:
      break;
    };
    thisHref += '?url=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
    thisLink.attr('href', thisHref);
   };
  })
 }
});
$('.special').fixLink();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="o-btn special" href="https://www.example.com/site#1">open</a>

<br>
<a class="o-btn special" href="https://www.example.com/site#2">open</a>

<br>
<a class="o-btn special" href="https://www.example.com/site#3">open</a>

<br>
<a class="o-btn special" href="https://www.example.com/site#4">open</a>

<br>
<a class="o-btn special" href="https://www.example.com/site#12">open</a>

<br>
```

[Fiddle playground](http://jsfiddle.net/01geytk3/9/)